# How to compare the latest version of a pass against old version to determine which fields have changed?

Tags: ios, passbook

The [Passbook Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW66) said:

> The device compares the latest version of the pass against the version it had before to determine which fields have changed.

My question is: in my own apps, how to determine which fields have changed? Does the pass have some field like version number to indicate pass update of the same pass type id and serial number?

Answer (score 0):

Also from the [Passbook Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Chapters/Apps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH6-SW1).

> To receive notifications when the pass library changes, register for
>   the PKPassLibraryDidChangeNotification notification. Pass the instance
>   of PKPassLibrary as the object. The pass library isn’t a singleton;
>   each instance sends its own notifications, and you want the
>   notifications from this particular instance. Use the
>   addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: method to specify that you
>   want to respond on the main queue and provide a block to handle the
>   notification. The user info dictionary of the notification describes
>   what changed. Alternately, use the dispatch_async and
>   dispatch_get_main_queue functions to respond on the main thread.

There is no version number as such, but you can check the contents or a hash of manifest.json.  If any of the hashes have changed, you will know that the pass has changed.